# Magento 2 :Error while checkout using Paypal

Tags: magento2, paypal-express

I got this error while checkout.

A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed.

currency is US Dollar($).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add valid Billing and Shipping address for Paypal, because while payment PayPal validate your address.

Comment: Hello @Jaimin, I have already disabled billing agreement in stores->configuration->sales->payment methods->paypalexpress->billing agreement . Then why should it validate ???

Comment: Customer address validation is not dependent on PayPal billing agreements. You can refer @ https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/shipping-address-outside